# URL Rewriting in PHP With Parametres

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Wamp server that is localhost is my server and "mysite" is my site folder name in WWW direcotry
Here is my URL

..../mysite/videos/show.php?id=535&category=books

want this

......./mysite/videos/show/id/category

My .htacces code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^videos/show/(.*)/(.*)$ /videos/show.php?id=$1&category=$2
```

But it is not working any help...

Comment: is your mod-rewrite module of apache enabled?

Comment: Could you make clearer which of the URLs should be given by the Browser and which one should be used in apache?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem 1 month ago. I found the answer thanks @anubhava. He`s suggestion work perfectly for me give it a try i hope to help you.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+videos/show\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&category=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /videos/show/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^videos/show/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /videos/show.php?id=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, its not working still i restart the wamp server but not working still

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /mysite
RewriteRule ^videos/show/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /videos/show.php?id=$1&category=$2
```

And Check mod-rewrite module of apache must be enable. If not than enable it and restart your server again.

Comment: Mr Suresh , yes it is enabled .

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /mysite
RewriteRule ^videos/show/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /videos/show.php?id=$1&category=$2

not working at all

Comment: No ,  go to the url not rewritng

Comment: tell us the error what u r getting? when u hit `http://localhost/mysite/videos/show/535/books` what does it shows in browser?

Comment: The error : The requested URL /mysite/videos/show/535/books was not found on this server.

Comment: Updated my post try with that.

Comment: can we chat on gtalk saeed.histone@gmail.com

Comment: hi the url rewriting is still not working if you can help will be very thankful to you.